# Error while compiling the nested table type in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I have created a type like this:

```
create or replace TYPE "DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017"
AS OBJECT
(
   programdata     VARCHAR2(2000)
)
```

Which is used by a nested table type

```
create or replace TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" AS TABLE OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;
```

and a table

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY_TABLE_25MAY17 OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;
```

Then I altered the type `DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017`

```
ALTER TYPE DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017
   MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (programdata VARCHAR2(4000)) CASCADE;
```

But now when I compile the type "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017 " I am getting the error

> "error: ora-22308: operation not allowed on evolved type".

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: also im getting a error while performing the frontend functionality related to this " java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SCHEMA.TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017 got SCHEMA.TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" .  Also the TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017  has dependency to package .view and trigger .

Comment: Tip for future reference: please make it easier for us to figure out what's going on with clear object naming. Three different things with virtually the same dummy name is unnecessary.

Comment: And the comment regarding `ORA-00932` is a separate question. The StackOverflow rule is one question per thread. So start a new question. Include **all the relevant details**. Link to this question if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> "But now if I compile the type "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017 " im getting the error"

It depends how you compile the nested table object. This error occurs with `create or replace`. The trick is to use `alter type ... compile` instead:

Here's your set-up:

```
SQL> create or replace TYPE "DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" AS OBJECT
  2  (programdata     VARCHAR2(2000));
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" AS TABLE OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE DUMMY_TABLE_25MAY17 OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;

Table created.
SQL>
```

Now apply the change.

```
SQL> ALTER TYPE DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017
  2     MODIFY ATTRIBUTE (programdata VARCHAR2(4000)) CASCADE;

Type altered.

SQL> create or replace TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" AS TABLE OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;
  2  /
create or replace TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" AS TABLE OF DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22308: operation not allowed on evolved type


SQL> alter TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" compile 
  2  /

Type altered.

SQL> insert into  DUMMY_TABLE_25MAY17 values ( DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017 ('this is a test'));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have also done the same thing :alter TYPE "TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017" compile .  but then also getting the error :"java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SCHEMA.TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017 got SCHEMA.TYP_DUMMY_TYPE_25MAY2017"